# Blockchain Application Architecture: UML & Use Cases

Tags: uml, blockchain, ethereum, use-case, decentralized-applications

For my internship, I need to implement a blockchain based solution to manage a drug supply chain. The management of this supply chain implies to track-and-trace (geolocate) a drug on the chain, but also to monitor the storage temperature to see if the cold chain is respected. For that I created a mock-up of the POC my Dapps (https://balsamiq.cloud/sum5oq5/p8lsped)and also I wanted to prepare myself by doing a UML and a use cases. However, I didn't find a lot of information about blockchain's UML and use cases besides two literatures which were quite different, so I don't know if what I did was correct or not...

---

### The users of my Dapps will be the following ones:

- The stakeholders (Manufacturers, Distributors and Retailers) which will use the Dapps to place orders and also monitor them. They also can search in the historic a specific order. Finally, trough IOT sensors they update the conditions of the order (temperature & location).
- The administrator which roles is to update the Dapps and its rules. But also to add or delete user while also defining the rights that they have on the blockchain (I intend to use a permisionned blockchain). Finally, they are also here to help in case of technical problem.

---

### The Dapps that I'm thinking about works in the following:

- A user, the customer, can place an order (a list of products) to a
  certain seller and choose the final destination of the order.
- The order is then put together before being shipped or stocked in the
  depots of one of the stakeholders (distributor or retailer) with a
  description of the stocking and/or shipping condition of the product
  (for example the product must be stocked or transported in a room
  with a temperature of less than 5°C). During the shipping and
  storing, an IOT device will feed the drops with the temperature and
  geolocation of the product by updating the data each 5-10mn.
  Obviously they will be a function that allows all the users to see
  the history of the order passed and search inside a specific order.
- In case where the temperature doesn't respect the temperature
  recommended, then the smart-contract send an alert. The same if the
  collocation of the product is "weird" like being in some European
  countries and not in an Asian country, an alert will be sent again by
  the smart-contractual. Finally, in the case where the product is sent
  to the asked location by the customer, then the money for the order
  will be paid to the seller.

---

So based on what I explained, I came here in hope that someone tell me if the use cases and UML that I did were correct or not.

[image]

[image]

I thank in advance anybody who'll take the time to help me.

Comment: How should we tell? We know nothing of the business behind. Syntactically your UCs look ok. Your classes? Well, what's your issue?

Comment: I don't know if there will be a change between the UML of blockchain-based application and one that is based on a centralized database. So my main problem is to see if what I did is not entirely wrong... I also added how my Dapps works, I completely forgot about it even trough I had it my Dapps's specification document.

Comment: Please use StackOverflow for simple, focused, questions which can have simple focused answers. Unfortunately your question is not suitable for StackOverflow format. I suggest you go to a generic Ethereum development discussion forum like /r/Dev.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I will do it like that then. Thanks for the information.